# Можно ли бесплатно организовать обновление программы?

Tags: qt, c++

Программой будут пользоваться несколько человек. Так что покупать сервер/хостинг для этой задачи - не вариант, но делать сервер на локальном компьютере - тоже не вариант. Может, есть какие-то способы с бесплатными файловыми хранилищами или ещё чем бесплатным? Кстати, пользователь будет просто уведомляться об обновление, а дальше все автоматически.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте для уведомлений использовать автоматическую рассылку писем по email, а для хранения обновленного дистрибутива используйте, например, dropbox или бесплатный хостинг, например, narod.ru, или hostinger.ru. Это не реклама, просто недавно о них тут писали, и они дают бесплатно 2Gb с apache, mysql и php. Можно записывать, кто скачал обновление и когда.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем у вас, собственно, проблема? Бесплатных вариантов размещения файлов вагон и две маленьких тележки - хоть дропбокс - гуглдрайв - яндексдрайв и прочие облачные хранилища, хоть всяческие сервисы типа narod.ru или тот же github.io. Положить на любой из вариантов файлик с описанием последней версии и саму версию и вперед, ну а из программы иногда проверять  его

Comment: @aknew, с яндекса можно давать прямые ссылки для программного скачивания обновлений? По-моему, там все через браузер только можно.

Comment: не знаю, не пробовал если честно. А вот с дропбоксом точно пробовал, гуглдрайв не помню, но кажется тоже